# How can I tell the Visual Studio 2013 debugger which graphics card I want to use?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, video-card

In my Computer I got two graphics cards and I want that the Visual Studio debugger uses the stronger one. I want that because I am programming a game and I got fps drops with the weaker one.
How can I do that?

EDIT: I have already tried to start Visual Studio 13 or my program with the stronger graphics card, but it is always using the weaker one.

Comment: What has this to do with the debugger, exactly? Isn't it a responsibility of your (3D) program/code to choose the graphics adapter it wants to use for rendering?

Comment: You can choose from the settings of your graphic cards which programs will use one or another.

Comment: My guess is that your code is configured to choose the primary monitor.  You could try changing your primary monitor to be the monitor that is attached to the stronger graphics card.